# Files in 000webhost are corrupting

Tags: php

I am using 000webhost to run this script in a php page:

```
<?php
header (‘Location: http://www.website.com/’);
$handle = fopen(“log.txt”, “a”);
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, “=”);
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, “rn”);
}
fwrite($handle, “rn”);
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

Yet when I save the file, it changes to this:

```
<?php
header (âLocation: http://www.website.com/â);
$handle = fopen(âlog.txtâ, âaâ);
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, â=â);
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, ârnâ);
}
fwrite($handle, ârnâ);
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

Is there any reason why it is doing this, and if so what can I do to stop it?

Comment: What text editor are you using, and how are you uploading the files?

Comment: You don't want that original script with the "smart quotes" anyway. Those should be `'` and `"` instead of `‘` and `“`.

Comment: Well, dont host your stuff there. You can get a full blown VPS for $5/mo or less.

Comment: find a decent hosting company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of your code, whatever editor you are using is putting in smart quotes (quotes that curve inward/outward). They are intended for documents but they are not supported in plain text. PHP code is plain text, so when you save your file and upload it to 000webhost, the quotes are being replaced with some other character.

Whatever text editor you are using, consider something else like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.4.html) or [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/3). If you don't want to or can't use a different editor, look for a setting to turn these "smart quotes" off.

Comment: Thank you, This fixed my problem perfectly!

Comment: To some people, they look good in documents. To other people, any potential aesthetic appeal is negated by the profound annoyance induced any time they appear.

Comment: True, I use them in doc's but it is subjective. Edited

Comment: Hey, I wasn't meaning to criticize your answer. Just my two cents. I actually meant it jokingly, (although it is true) but the tone is totally lost in print, of course.